# Development Tools Group is not available in RedHat 8 Docker Image

Tags: dockerfile, nvidia-docker, dnf, redhat-containers

I am trying to build a docker image from the Nvidia RedHat 8 base image: nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-base-ubi8 that is available at [nvidia's docker image hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags?page=1&name=base-ubi8&ordering=last_updated).

In the dockerfile, I was trying to install the "Development Tools" group.

`RUN dnf -y group install "Development Tools"`

I got the following error:

> Module or Group "Development Tools" is not available.

When I ran the following command to check

> dnf grout list

the group "Development Tools" is indeed not available.

How can I add and install the "Development Tools" group in the base image? Thanks!